# Fitnesse.NET Testrunner not running SuiteSetUp

Tags: .net, command-line, fitnesse

My folder structure is like this:

```
SuiteSetUp 
TestSuite
-Test 1
-Test 2
. . .
-Test n
```

When I run the suite through Fitnesse in the webbrowser, the suitesetup is called correctly. However, if I call TestRunner.exe from the command line like so

```
testrunner -c "configFile" -results "resultsFile" localhost 8080 "TheSuite"
```

it fails to run the SuiteSetUp, and only runs each of the tests in the suite instead. Since the tests rely on the setup, the tests fail, but I havent figured out why this is happening.

Answer (score 0):

The TestRunner protocol has been deprecated. See instead http://fitnesse.org/FitNesse.UserGuide.CommandLineRestCommands

Comment: Is there a way to have this output the results in the colored fitnesse page summary like if I were to run this through fitnesse in the webbrowser?

Comment: This is almost working, but when I attempt to run the suite FitServer crashes. Looking at the source it crashes when trying to load and XML file from the path of my suite. Any idea what XML file this is? Some config file?

Comment: The -c switch specifies a config file. See http://fitsharp.github.com/FitSharp/SuiteConfigurationFile.html